# Weak Convergence of finite signed Measures is not metriziable (Probability Theory : Klenke 13.2.7)

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, solution-verification

currently I am trying to solve the following exercise in Klenke's Book called Probability theory (Exercise 13.2.7) that proves that the topology of weak convergence is generally not metriziable.

Let me first recall from the background of this exercise:

> - Let $E$ be a set, we denote by $\mathcal{M}(E) = \{\mu : E \to \mathbb R \mid \mu \text{ is a finite measure}\}$ the set of finite measures on $E$. Secondly we call $\mathcal{M}_R(E) = \{\mu : E \to \mathbb R \mid \mu \text{ is a Radon measure}\}$ the set of Radon measures on $E$.
> - Extend the notion of weak convergence and vague convergence to signed measures. More precisely, we are going to denote a signed measure $\nu$ via $\nu=\nu^{+} - \nu^{-}$, where both measures are both finite or Radon measures.
> - The exercise wants to prove that the weak convergence from probability theory is generally not metriziable. We are going to perform this task by taking $E = [0,1]$ and showing that there exists no metric that metrizises the weak convergence of Radon measures, hence there is no metric for finite measures aswell.

The exercise is split in the following:

> - 1. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ take $\nu_n = \delta_{\frac{1}{n}}-\delta_{\frac{2}{n}}$ where $C>0$ and prove that this converges weakly to $0$-measure on $M(E)$.
> - 2. Assume there is a metric that induces weak convergence. Show that then there
>      exists a sequence $(C_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that $C_n \to \infty$ and $C_n \nu_n \to 0$ in the weak sense.
> - 3. Choose $f \in C[0,1]$ such that $f(2^{-n}) = (-1)^{n} C^{-1/2}_n$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$
>      and prove that $\int f d(C_n \nu_n)$ does not converge to $0$.
> - 4. Conclude.

Before getting started I need the following Lemma (Klenke $13.11$):

> Let $(E,d)$ be a metric space be a metric space then $\text{Lip}_1(E;[0,1])$ is a separating family of measures, i.e. $$\forall f \in \text{Lip}_1(E;[0,1] \cap L^1(\mu) \cap L^1(\nu)): \int_E f d\mu = \int_E f d\nu \;  \implies \nu = \mu$$

Alright here is what I have done so far:

1. Take any $C>0$ and let $f \in C_b[0,1]$ be arbitary then directly by definition we have
   $$
   \int_E f d\nu_n = C \left(f(1/n) - f(2/n) \right) \to C \left(f(0) - f(0) \right) = 0 \quad \text{ as } n \to \infty,
   $$
   since $f$ is continuous and bounded.
2. Assume that there exists a metric $d_{w}$ that metrizies the weak convergence on $E$. Then $(\mathcal{M}_R(E),d_w)$ is a metric space. Then applying lemma $1$ it sufficies to test the weak convergence on the set of Lipschitz function on $E$ with Lipschitz constant $1$. Hence let $f : E \to \mathbb R$ be Lipschitz and take $(C_n \nu_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ then observe that
   $$
   \int_E f d(C_n \nu_n) = \sqrt{n} \left( f(1/n) - f(2/n) \right) \stackrel{\text{Lip}_1}{\leq} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{1}  \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n} \right) \to 0 \quad \text{ as } n \to \infty,
   $$
   This sufficies.
3. We want to prove that $\int_{E} f d(C_n \nu_n)$ does not converge to $0$ for some suitable $f \in C[0,1]$. It sufficies to prove that there exists a $f \in C[0,1]$ and a subsequence of $(C_n \nu_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$, such that the above integral diverges. Hence choose $f \in C[0,1]$ such that $f(2^{-k}) = (-1)^{k} \times C^{-1/2}_k$ and let $(C_{2^k} \nu_{2^k})_{k \in \mathbb N}$ be a subsequence of measures such that
   $$
   C_{2^k} \nu_{2^k} = C_{2^k} \left( \delta_{\frac{1}{2^k}} - \delta_{\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}} \right).
   $$
   Then observe that
   $$
   \int_{E} f d(C_{2^k} \nu_{2^k}) = C_{2^k} \left( f(2^{-k}) - f(2^{-(k+1)}) \right) = C_{2^k} \left((-1)^k \times C^{-1/2}_{k} - (-1)^{k+1} \times C^{-1/2}_{k+1} \right).
   $$
   Using $C_k = \sqrt{k}$ yields that the above is simply
   $$
   (-1)^{k} \times 2^{k/2} \left(\frac{1}{2^{k/4}} + \frac{1}{2^{(k+1)/4}} \right), 
   $$
   but this clearly divergence and hence we are done.
4. Assume that there exists a metric $d_w : \mathcal{M}(E) \times \mathcal{M}(E) \to [0,\infty)$ that metrizes the weak convergence on $\mathcal{M}(E)$. By $2.$ we know that $(C_n \nu_{n})_{n \in \mathbb N} \in \mathcal{M}(E)$ has to converge to $0$, which by using $(c)$ ends in a contradiction. Thus no such metric $d_w$ can exist.

I have some questions following up this exercise:

**Questions:**

1. Is my prove correct? More details?
2. How can one guess that the result is true by maybe using functional analysis? I don't fully get the idea of the proof, it seems that we built a sequence of measure that converges to $0$ ''fast enough'' (satisfying a linear Lipschitz bound), hence yields $(b)$ however since one uses signed measures one can built alternating sequences, but I don't understand how one can come up with this idea.
3. What is the largest class of signed measures or measures generally that still admits a metrization of weak convergence?

I am grateful for any answer to these questions.

Comment: notice that the space $\mathcal{M}$ of complex (or finite signed) measures is a linear space. To topology on $\mathcal{M}$ is the weak topology $\sigma(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{C}_b(E))$. For (2) Suppose there is a translation invariant metric $d$ that generate this topology.You are asked to shoe that for any $d(\mu_n,0)\rightarrow0$ in $\mathcal{M}$, there is $C_n>0$ $C_n\nearrow\infty$ such that $d(C_n\mu_n,0)\rightarrow0$.

Comment: Are you sure that you are suppose to prove that for any $\mu_{n \in \mathbb N}$ this property holds, in the exercise he uses $\nu_n$ in the same notation as in the first part indicating that he is specifically interested in $\nu_n = \delta_{1/n} - \delta_{2/n}$, so I am surprised by your comment or did I got your comment wrong?